# Change to void or keep the return values

Tags: java, refactoring, void, return-type

I'm doing  refactoring/review of a Java application

When I'm doing that I show that some of method has
return values such as `Object`, `String`, `Boolean`, etc., but
return values are not used in any places. Only have done the method calling.

So, I'm just wandering keeping them as it is will cause the
performance issue for application.

Should I change them to void or keep them as it is?

Comment: If you are eventually going to use return values, you should keep them. If not, there is no need to keep them. Keep in mind that you can still use `return;` in a method with `void` to exit the method early.

Comment: can some body explain me what actually happen in JVM when you have a return type and void

Comment: @Baz +1 The opposite is not true, you have to place `return` statement if the method is not return `void`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think that there would be a performance penalty to keeping the return types like they are.

That being said, I think that you should still remove them. The reason is that they are essentially dead code. There might be unknown bugs lurking in those methods revolving around the return types - unknown because they are not used. This is a potential danger if someone decides to use them one day.

Furthermore, the maintenance burden is increased if you keep them: Everytime someone touches one of these methods, she has to (unnecessarily) think about the return type.

This essentially boils down to YAGNI.

Answer (score 4):

- Moreover than being a performance hit its an **inappropriate construction of a method**.
- If the method's returned value has **no** use in the program then there is no reason to return it, and so the method's return type should be made `void`.

Comment: can some body explain me what actually happen in JVM when you have a return type and void

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, either the API is being incorrectly used or it is incorrectly designed.

If the API is correctly designed then why are the API users not using the method return types? In this case the users must be wrong.

On the other hand if the API is incorrectly designed, what is the point of using it in its current state? If the returned information is superfluous then fix the API and make the methods void.

I think that performance considerations would be of little importance when compared to a good API design. Performance can always be improved later, but APIs are very difficult and expensive to change.

Answer (score 1):

Should not return a value if the value in not used. Use `void` instead. Sometimes I see some *getters* that is not used but actually they are used by the web framework. It's difficult to determine if the method is unused. Even if it's used but the return value is ignored. There's no restriction to not ignore the return value.